# Spring batch reader - How to avoid returning a list of objects

Tags: spring, spring-batch

So I have a spring batch app that I have getting a list of ids that it then uses 'read()' on to get 1 to many results back. The issue is, I have no control over how many results I get back for each id meaning that my chunking is spotty at best. Is there a suggested way to avoid spikes in memory/cpu? An example is below:

```
@Before
public void getIds() {
    *getListOfIds* //Usually around 10,000 or so
}

@Override
public AccountObject read() {
    if(list of ids havent all been used) {
        List<AccountObject> myAccounts = myService.getAccounts(id);
        return myAccounts; //This could be anywhere from 1 result to 100,000 results.
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So the myAccounts object above could be small or huge. This causes chunking to basically be useless because at the moment I am chunking by List. I'd really rather chunk by straight AccountObject but don't see an easy way to do this.

Is there a class, strategy, etc. that I am missing here?

Comment: Have you considered paging the query?

Comment: you could split it into two steps, step-1 to fetch `AccountObject` List and stage it somewhere.
Then step-2 to fetch that staged data and work on it based on your chunk size.